# Execute MySQL Query using batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have installed mysql Server(5.7) in a remote server. i want to create a batch file to run my sql query. the batch file is present in my local system.

i am unable to point to remorte server where mysql is installed using batch script and unable to run the batch file.

Comment: Which remote server you are using windows / linux ?

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` is preconfigured to listen only to local connections.
You have to enable remote connections and grant the user you are using to connect remotely.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html